# "Could not find driver" ao definir página raiz da aplicação

Tags: php, postgresql, driver

Ao rodar o comando `php -S localhost:8080 -t public` O erro acima é acionado quanto tento realizar uma conexão com o postgres. Outras aplicações conseguem acessar normalmente quando as acesso pela url do servidor local. Todas as extensões e módulos necessários para o postgres executar já estão ativados.

Answer (score 1):

Entrei nas configurações do arquivo php.ini, da versão 7.0.10, instalada no servidor e descomentei a linha `extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll`. Suponho que, ao rodar o servidor pelo comando anteriormente listado, o mesmo colocava a fazia o deploy do servidor pela versão 7 do php, a qual não estava habilitada a extensão do Postgres.